# Сколько по времени подключать firebase? (analytics, crash reporting)

Tags: android, firebase

кто работал с firebase, подскажите как долго подключать к проекту firbase **analytics** и **crash reporting**?
Немного посмотрел мануалы, на первый взгляд вроде как нажать пару кнопок и пару строчек вписать, так ли это на самом деле? или с реальным проектом по всплывают подводные камни?

...сейчас полный завал по работе, нету времени выделить на это, а заказчик хочет знать сколько на это нужно время.

Comment: Практика показывает, что на осознание заказчиком, на кой ляд ему сдались firbase analytics и crash reporting или <произвольная хотелка> может уйти на порядок больше времени, чем на их подключение. Ну а если он это уже осознал и все четко представляет, то, наверное, и в сроках ориентировался бы.

Comment: будучи Junior при первом подключение analytics, crash с fabric ушло 2-2.5 часа.